# Git Errors/File not found

Tags: git, webstorm

I have a working application. I deleted an html file from project, added changes to git and committed them. Then created another html of the same name in the same location, now my editor continues to throw an error 'Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory''

Will adding and committing to git help?

Comment: did you add/commit already?

Comment: yes I had, after deleting file and making other changes, i added and committed all changes

Comment: But I don't mean "when you deleted the file, did you commit?". That's already stated on the question. I mean: when you re-created the file (after deleting and committing it), did you add and commit it?

Comment: Restart WebStorm

Comment: @Edmundo: yes I tried recreating file and committing it, infact I also renamed the file and tried

Comment: @Lissy: let me try that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed below steps to solve it - I think it was purely a Webstorm issue.

1) Deleted existing file (which was throwing the error: cannot resolve file)
2) Added same file
3) but this time under a different name

Seems weird but it solved it